# Erro 500 reporting Services Asp Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resources, reporting-services

Estou tentando renderizar um relatório desenvolvido em reporting services porém esta dando erro em alguma resource e não renderiza nada e me retorna o seguinte erro:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Quando eu rodava a aplicação local funcionava, só foi trocar para o IIS que começou a dar este erro, não tenho certeza se é um erro em alguma resource da aplicação.

Poderiam me ajudar por gentileza, estou há 1 semana com esse erro rs.

Comment: Erro 500 pode ser qualquer erro. Provavelmente sua aplicação tá lançando uma exceção. Usa um try-catch pra logar o erro da exceção, assim você saberá o que realmente está errado.

Comment: @Renan eu devo colocar um try catch onde ? pois não sei se o erro esta no script, view ou controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro estava ocorrendo por conta de um [maxLength] em um atributo int, limitei os tamanhos do campo na view mesmo.